# How to retrieve output/result from Parse Cloud Code on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I've set up a cloud code function that creates a string. I would therefore like to receive this string through Swift.

**Cloud Code Function:**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("customer", function(request, response){
stripe.customers.create({
    email: request.params.useremail
}, function(err, customer) {
    if(err){
            console.log(err);
            response.error(err);
    } 
    else{
            console.log(customer);
            console.log(customer.id);
            response.success(customer);
});
});
```

**Swift Code**

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("customer", withParameters: ["useremail": self.userEmailAdressTextField.text ?? ""], block: { (success: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
              print("The result is \(success)")
              print("The customer success ID is \(success?.objectForKey("id"))")
              print("The customer ID is \(success?.objectForKey("customer.id"))")
})
```

The Cloud Code function works as I am able to create a customer and have the output "customer.id" (string) printed in the Cloud Code log. I've tried printing the results in Xcode to see what happens, but every single object I refer to are marked as "nil".

Comment: I hope you are not getting error also. So instead of passing the customer object directly try by passing as dictionary object "var resultObject = {"result" : customer}";response.success(resultObject);.

Comment: Thank you, I did your function in Cloud Code, now how do I retrieve it with Swift? As in, sending it to the iOS app.

Comment: In success block type cast success object to dictionary and get the customer object from "results " key. I hope this will work.

Comment: So like this?  `PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("customer", withParameters: ["useremail": self.userEmailAdressTextField.text ?? ""], block: { (success: NSDictionary?, error: NSError?) -> Void in`

                                                                   I get the error: **Cannot convert value of type NSDictionary, NSError -> Void to expected argument type PFIdResultBlock**

Comment: No. you have to convert the argument success(what you mentioned in question is correct) no need to change in method definition.

Comment: Thank you. So I applied what you said and did this:     
**Swift**

`print("The customer ID is \(success?.objectForKey("result"))")`

**Cloud Code**
          `console.log(customer);
   var resultObject = {"result" : customer.id};
   response.success(resultObject);
       response.success(customer);`

However, I still get "nil" as a result of this. Could you please apply your solution on my question and update the code?

Comment: Is it working??

Comment: No. Therefore, if you don't mind, can you please update my code to your code on my question? Perhaps I'm doing something wrong.